# Understanding "cat proc/net/udp"

Tags: linux, network-programming, udp

```
# cat /proc/net/udp | egrep "sl|3ADBFE0A"
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode ref pointer drops             
   16: 3ADBFE0A:007B 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000    74        0 40124 2 f203ca80 0                 
  509: 3ADBFE0A:0868 00000000:0000 07 00008C00:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 79208333 2 ea226340 0
```

I would like to seek for deeper and more beginner friendly explanation of the fields of the "cat proc/net/udp" output, especially the tx_queue. If I am correct with my understanding that when this [tx_queue] value is greater than 0 meaning that there are more packets that are waiting to be sent and that the application is not fast enough to send those packets?

Comment: You can try posting at http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/, you might get more answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the other way round: If your application is faster in producing data than the network adapter is in sending it (which is usually the case), then `tx_queue` is > 0.

The `tx_queue` is the kernel memory currently being used by outgoing packets which have not been sent. They have not yet been sent, because the kernel and the network adapter (not the application) were not able to send them yet, most likely because they were busy sending other stuff.

It is perfectly normal to have a moderate amount of data waiting in this buffer for  a very short time.

An application usually does not need to worry at all about any of these numbers.